# How to Remove a "Yahoo!" Alias?

Tags: user-accounts, alias, yahoo-mail

As it can be noticed in the following Screen-Shot, I have discovered that I still have a *Yahoo!* Alias that I hoped that I deleted quite a while ago. I am talking about the `Varada_PRADA` alias.

[image: Yahoo! Groups Screen-Shot]

This Screen-Shot comes from the following Uniform Resource Locator:

https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/all/manage/edit

I have not found yet any way to remove this *Yahoo!* Alias.

My guess is that the *Yahoo!* Network is changing so fast, that they have not been able yet to update all of their former Settings.

I have already asked this question on the [*Yahoo!* Answers Web-Site](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20171231130647AAyRqFX), but the only solution that has arisen so far has been to remove the Account that has this Alias.

Unfortunately, this Solution has the drawback that, by removing the Account, not only the Alias is removed, but also the main Identifier is removed with it.

Does anyone know how to remove this *Yahoo!* Alias?